# String Split and get some data

Tags: java, string, split

```
String s = "Total Count :2, Correct Count :1, Wrong Count:1, Correct :India is great,, Wrong: where aer you";
```

What i want:

- Total Count
- Correct Count
- Wrong Count

in `int` variables.

This is fairly new to me, I hope you guys will help me.

Comment: Have you read the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: What I want: http://img0.gtsstatic.com/wallpapers/c789639a11a000fc0e9d2438962de741_large.jpeg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    String s = "Total Count :2, Correct Count :1,Wrong Count:1, Correct :India is great,, Wrong: where aer you";

    String[] ints = s.split("[^0-9]+");

    int totalCount = Integer.parseInt(ints[1]);
    int correctCount = Integer.parseInt(ints[2]);
    int wrongCount = Integer.parseInt(ints[3]);

    System.out.println(totalCount + " " + correctCount + " " + wrongCount); //2 1 1
```

Comment: @aashish_soni, if it what you want, then you should accept my answer, i think ;)